# JQuery list filter wont work with wrong characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, filter

I have this filter for a html list I have gotten from [Keyup filter multiple lists with headers with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625811/keyup-filter-multiple-lists-with-headers-with-jquery). The problem is that once you type a wrong word/character that's not in the list, it kinda breaks and and wont work until you completely erase/delete it from the input box. Is there any way to fix the original code so that it works even after you simply backspace and erase the wrong character?

http://jsfiddle.net/thesystemrestart/zzG4f/5/

HTML:

```
<ul id="workflow_books">    
<li>
    <h6 class="custom"> Custom Books</h6>

    <ul>
        <li class="custom-books">
            <a>Don't see your book in our list? Add it yourself!</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <h6>Academic</h6>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>Academic Book One</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a>Academic Book Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>        
    <h6>Botany</h6>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>Botany Book One</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a>Botany Book Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
var $products = $('#workflow_books li ul');
$("#search").keyup(function() {
    var val = this.value.trim();
    if (!val) $('li:hidden', '#workflow_books').show();
    else {
        $('li:hidden', $products).show();
        $('li', $products).filter(function() {
            var re = new RegExp(val, 'ig');
            return !re.test($('a', this).text());
        }).hide();
        $products.each(function() {
            if ($('li:visible', this).length == 0) $(this).parent('li').hide();
            else $(this).parent('li').show();
        });
    }
});
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
$('li:hidden', $products).show();
```

doesn't show the parents if the parents have been hidden, so this line:

```
if ($('li:visible', this).length == 0)
```

can never be false when the parent is hidden.

My main change was to the first line I posted above:

```
$('li:hidden', '#workflow_books').show();
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hKv8h/

```
var $products = $('#workflow_books li ul:not(:first)');
$("#search").keyup(function() {
    var val = this.value.trim();
    $('li:hidden', '#workflow_books').show();
    if (val) {
        $('li:hidden', '#workflow_books').show();
        $('li', $products).filter(function() {
            var re = new RegExp(val, 'ig');
            return !re.test($('a', this).text());
        }).hide();
        $products.each(function() {
            if ($('li:visible', this).length == 0) 
                $(this).parent('li').hide();
            else 
                $(this).parent('li').show();
        });
    }
});
```